# Как правильно делать копию состояния в reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux, state, копирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему state после обработки экшена не изменяется?

```
let initialState = {
  questions: [
    {
      name: 'Вопрос 1',
      id: 1,
      answers: [{ name: '1', isRight: false, id: 1, isSelected: false },
      { name: '2', isRight: true, id: 2, isSelected: false },
      { name: '3', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: false },
      { name: '4', isRight: false, id: 4, isSelected: false },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'вопрос 2', id: 2,
      answers: [
        { name: 'первый ответ 2', isRight: true, id: 1, isSelected: false },
        { name: 'второй овтет 2', isRight: false, id: 2, isSelected: false },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

reducer:

```
if (action.type === SET_ANSWER) {
    let stateCopy = { ...state };
    stateCopy.questions = [...state.questions];
    stateCopy.questions.map((question) => {
      if (question.id === action.questionNumber) {
        return {...question.answers.map((answer) => {
          if (answer.id === action.selectedAnswer) {
            return { ...answer, isSelected: true }
          }
          return { ...answer }
        })}
      }
      return {...question}
    })
    return stateCopy;
  }
  return state;
```

В итоге в state в массиве answers должно поменяться значение isSelected c false на true, но этого не происходит. Логика в обработке экшена у меня вроде правильная, подозреваю, что моя ошибка в том, что я неправильно делаю копию состояния.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правилно думаете, таким образом делается копия объекта в котором нет вложенных объектов/массивов. Если же есть вложенные объекты/массивы нужно их копировать вручную, ну или подключать сторонние библиотеки. В данном случае можно сделать так:

```
 const { questionNumber, selectedAnswer } = action;

 const newState = {
   questions: initialState.questions.map((question) =>
     question.id === questionNumber
       ? {
           ...question,
           answers: question.answers.map((answer) =>
             answer.id === selectedAnswer
               ? { ...answer, isSelected: true }
               : answer
           ),
         }
       : question
   ),
 };

 return newState;
```

Этот код:

```
stateCopy.questions.map((question) => {
  if (question.id === action.questionNumber) 
  ...
```

ничего не делает, так как `map` не мутирует объект он как раз возврашает копию. Результат `map` нужно сохранять в переменную или передавать в функцию.

```
const newCopyOfArray = arr.map(item=>item + 1)
```